# Deploying a Java project on Linux system

Tags: java, linux, deployment

I developed a project using Java and now I've to deliver it to client who is using Linux. Which executable file format will be delivered and how to make that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well basically what you wanna put in a .sh file is the commands you'd normally type at the console to run your jar file. They should be separated by a new line (i.e. each on a separate line in the .sh file).

The most basic you can go is add something like this to your sh file:

```
java -Xms=64m -Xmx=256m -jar myJar.jar -classpath [dependencies dir]/dep1.jar,[dependencies dir]/dep2.jar
```

beyond this you can do more exotic stuff, like parametrise some environment variables, get command line argumens from when the .sh is launched and pass them to the jar executatble etc. Look up "bash scripting" for advanced stuff:

http://tldp.org/HOWTO/Bash-Prog-Intro-HOWTO-2.html#ss2.1

Answer (score 6):

Executable file format?

If you're delivering a Java app, give them a jar file (and associated libs).

Provide a shell script to set up its environment and execute it.

For example, assuming I define `ROOT_DIR` as my app's install directory, and so on:

```
CLASSPATH="${ADD_JARS}:${CLASSPATH}:${ROOT_DIR}/lib/myApp.jar:\
${ROOT_DIR}/lib/jibx/jibx-run.jar:\
${ROOT_DIR}/lib/jibx/xpp3.jar:\
${ROOT_DIR}/lib/bindings.jar:\
${ROOT_DIR}/lib/commons-lang-2.0.jar:\
${ROOT_DIR}/lib/forms-1.0.5.jar"
"${JAVACMD}" -Xmx256M -DanyDefsNeeded=foobar -Dbase.dir="${ROOT_DIR}" -cp "${CLASSPATH}" myApp.main.Launcher "$@"
```

What goes into the shell script depends totally on what your app actually needs to start up.

Comment: and i actually want to know how to make a shell script to setup its environment and execute it?

Comment: "java -jar FILENAME.jar" will run your JAR file, provided it has a Main-Class declared and the client has the JVM installed. Depending on your development environment (e.g. NetBeans) the former may be done for you already.

Comment: @MohammadFaisal Updated answer with a really simple example.

Answer (score 4):

A jar. If it is not executable, then a script (.sh) to launch the jar.

Comment: how do i create a shell script file (.sh) and how to execute that jar?

Comment: You can create a shell script using any text editor.  The manual entry for the `java` command explains how to execute a JAR file.

Comment: How to create script: type `echo "java -jar myJarFileName.jar" >> launcher.sh` in the jar directory and it should create a file named launcher.sh

Answer (score 2):

You might have better luck using [Launch4J](http://launch4j.sourceforge.net/), [IzPack](http://izpack.org/) or other [installer](http://java-source.net/open-source/installer-generators) that has cross-platform capabilities. This might be a better first option than trying to understand the intricacies and idiosyncrasies of the different Linux distributions and shells.

Comment: are these `Launch4j`, `IzPack` or other are available for `linux` also?

Answer (score 1):

If your app. has a GUI, the best user experience for installation/deployment can be had by way of [Java Web Start](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/java-web-start/info).  Note that JWS can deploy apps. to Windows, *nix **and** Mac. and avoids all the maintenance woes of generating 3 separate (platform specific) executables.