# What is the best way to deliver java software on Linux?

Tags: java, linux

I'm having a Java project which is cross-platform. For Windows and Mac OS X I deliver .EXE or .APP files generated by "launch4j" and "jarbundler" via an ANT task.

Now I'm searching for a way to deliver this piece of software to Linux users, too.
At the moment, all I have is a runnable JAR.

Is there a better way than delivering a runnable JAR packed as .tar.gz?
Probably an easy way where the executable shows the programs icon (which a runnable JAR can't)?

Comment: Did you consider making your software free software (e.g. GPLv3 licensed)? Then users could compile it, and distributions could package it....

Comment: If it has a GUI, [Java Web Start](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/java-web-start/info).

Comment: @AndrewThompson it has. I'll take a look at this...

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch it is free software. Have to check all the licensing stuff first since I'm using some other open source libraries...

Comment: On Linux, you might consider making a tiny shell script running that `jar` ....

Comment: There's a similar question at http://stackoverflow.com/q/7794493/1741542

Comment: http://launch4j.sourceforge.net/ supports Linux. What is the real question?

Comment: @Jayan launch4j is only for wrapping JARs in Windows executables. the question is about delivering a JAR on Linux

Comment: The documentation claim to support Linux. If it can support MAC, there is good chance to get linux working as well.

Comment: @Jayan launch4j runs on linux, okay. But it GENERATES ONLY windows executables (exe files). That's not the question here...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just create a menu shortcut, though a .desktop file similar to this:

```
[Desktop Entry]
Categories=Games
Exec=java -jar YOURJARFILE.jar
Icon=YOURICON.png
Name=Application Name
Type=Application
```

(full specs on http://www.freedesktop.org/wiki/Specifications/desktop-entry-spec)

Then install it using:

xdg-desktop-menu install YOURAPP.desktop